# JDBC Connection to SQL Server using R

Tags: r, sql-server, rjdbc

I am getting below error while trying to run this script which should connect to MSSQL server

```
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)
drv <- RJDBC::JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
           "/home/infa/SQL_JDBC/sqljdbc_10.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar")

conn <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, url='jdbc:sqlserver://server_name.com;databaseName=MY_DB;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true' , user="USER", password="PWD")
print(conn)
output<- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM MY_DB.TABLE_NAME")
print(output)
```

While running above script I am getting this error

```
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava
Error in errorCondition(paste0(..., "\n  JDBC ERROR: ", .jcall(x, "S",  : 
  could not find function "errorCondition"
Calls: dbGetQuery ... dbSendQuery -> .local -> .verify.JDBC.result -> .verify.ex
Execution halted
```

**Environment**:unix
**R version** 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"
**RJDBC Version** :
packageVersion("RJDBC")
[1] ‘0.2.10’
**rJava Version**:
packageVersion("rJava")
[1] ‘0.9.11’
**DBI Version**:
packageVersion("DBI")
[1] ‘1.0.0’

Comment: What version of JDK are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line:

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, url='jdbc:sqlserver://server_name.com;databaseName=MY_DB;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true' , user="USER", password="PWD")
```

With that line:

```
conn <- RJDBC::dbConnect(drv, url='jdbc:sqlserver://server_name.com;databaseName=MY_DB;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true' , user="USER", password="PWD")
```

Looks like you are using DBI package. Replace with RJDBC package to match library(RJDBC) use condition.

You could try change your R version to one update. Here old versions of R are incopatibles to new one. 3.2.2 R is incompatible to RJDBC 0.2.10.